# Question about the proof of Theorem 3.1.4 in Marker's Model Theory, An Introduction

Tags: model-theory

On page 73 of Marker's *Model Theory, An Introduction* the following theorem can be found:

**Theorem 3.1.4** *Suppose that $L$ contains a constant symbol $c$, $T$ is an $L$-theory, and $\varphi ( \bar v)$ is an $L$-formula. The following are equivalent:*

*i) There is a quantifier-free $L$-formula $\psi ( \bar v )$ such that $T \models \forall \bar v \, ( \varphi (\bar v) \leftrightarrow \psi (\bar v) )$.*

*ii) If $M$ and $N$ are models of $T$, $A$ is an $L$-structure, $A \subseteq M$, and $A \subseteq N$, then $M \models \varphi (\bar a)$ if and only if $N \models \varphi (\bar a)$ for all $\bar a \in A$.*

The proof of i) $\Rightarrow$ ii) is easy.

To show ii) $\Rightarrow$ i), Marker makes a case distinction. He first supposes $T \models \forall \bar v \, \varphi ( \bar v )$: then $T \models \forall \bar v \, ( \varphi (v) \leftrightarrow c = c )$, so we're done. Similarly if $T \models \forall \bar v \, \neg \varphi ( \bar v )$, then we're done because $T \models \forall \bar v \, ( \varphi (v) \leftrightarrow c \neq c )$.

After that, he states: *Thus, we may assume that both $T ∪ \{\varphi (\bar v)\}$ and $T ∪ \{\neg \varphi (\bar v)\}$ are satisfiable.* Of course, I agree with this statement - this is not an issue.

My problem lies in the fact that in the subsequent proof that Marker gives it is not at all clear to me *where* this assumption is used. (Note that at no spot he explicitly mentions the usage of this assumption.)

So my concrete **question** is: where is this assumption used in Marker's proof?

I think it *should* be used somewhere, otherwise it seems that the assumption the language have at least one constant can be omitted from the statement.

(NB: Alas, the complete proof is a little lengthy to post here.)

Answer (score 1):

See proof page 74; Marker wants to prove the **Claim** :

> $T \cup \Gamma(\overline d) \vDash \phi(\overline d)$.

He proceeds by contradiction, assuming : $\mathcal M \vDash T \cup \Gamma(\overline d) \cup \{ \lnot \phi(\overline d) \}$.

This, I think, is the point ... If one of $T \cup \{ \phi(\overline v) \}$ or $T \cup \{ \lnot \phi(\overline v) \}$ were *unsatisfiable*, "adding" to $T$ the new premises $\Gamma$ will not change this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still, I do not understand where it's used. As you justly state, he supposes $M$ is a model of this theory. In order this be possible, it _has_ to be the case that $M \cup \{ \neg \varphi ( \bar d ) \}$ is satisfiable, right? (Otherwise there cannot even be such a structure $M$.) That is, it is certainly a _necessary_ assumption. The weird thing is that, when I go through the proof, I still do not see in which step (inference) it is used.

Comment: @BodaPoldi - I think that the "step" is exactly that : if $T \cup \{ ¬ \phi(v) \}$ is not satisfiable, then also $T \cup \Gamma(d) \cup \{ ¬ \phi(d) \}$ is not, and thus he cannot assume the existence of $\mathcal M$.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought about that. However, we get this structure $M$ (because of the assumption) _by contradiction_, right? So we don't use anything there: if it doesn't exist, then what we wanted to show (namely $T \cup \Gamma ( \bar d ) \models \varphi ( \bar d )$) is trivial. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Marker is rather messy on this point. It is a minor point (that is why nobody cares) but it may confuse students.

When Marker defines formulas he forgets a connective: the 0-ary Boolean connective $\top$ (or $\bot$, if you prefer). The role of this connective is merely formal: it allows you to write a quantifier-free sentence also in languages without constants.

You need to have it otherwise relational theories (e.g. dense linear orders, random graphs) would never have elimination of quantifiers for a trivial reason: there is no quantifier-free sentence equivalent to $\forall x\ (x=x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand (and in fact already understood) this point about quantifier elimination and languages without constant symbol. It does not, however, seem to answer my question: where in the proof does Marker use the assumption (the one which I stated in my question)?

Comment: At some point he defines $A$ to be the structure generated by $\bar d$. If $\bar d$ is the empty tuple and the language has no constants, then $A=\varnothing$. Marker does not allow empty structures! (A choice that makes degenerated cases not seamless.)

Comment: This is a very good point. I agree with you that if $\bar d$ is the empty tuple (corresponding to the fact that $\varphi$ is a _sentence_), and the language doesn't have any constant symbols, then $A$ would be the "empty" structure (so it wouldn't exist). Still, where does Marker use the hypotheses  that $T ∪ \{\varphi (\bar v)\}$ and $T ∪ \{\neg \varphi (\bar v)\}$ are satisfiable?